# SFINAE not working with member function of template class

Tags: c++, sfinae

I have a template class where I would like to remove a member function if the type satisfies some condition, that, as far as I understand, should be a very basic usage of SFINAE, for example:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    template<typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
    T foo () {
        return 1.23;
    }
};
```

However, this is results in an error "no type named 'type'", like SFINAE was not going on. This however works if `foo` is a function not member of a class. What is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: It does work as expected: https://godbolt.org/z/M4cseYjz6

Comment: @Genjutsu No it doesn't? Since you didn't call it anywhere, there should've been no errors.

Comment: Introducing `typename U = T` for the member function (and then using `U` in SFINAE) fixes this. But if C++20 is available, you should be using `requires`.

Comment: .. or `static_assert`

Comment: Is [C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/GKrWYq1hf) an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dependent name for the compiler to use for SFINAE. Try something like this instead:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    template<typename Tp = T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<Tp>::value, Tp>::type
    foo () {
        return 1.23;
    }
};

int main() {
    A<double> a;
    a.foo();
}
```

If the type T is not floating point, the declaration would be malformed (no return type) and the function would not be considered for the overload set.

See it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TfTKT1Pro).

Comment: exact same problem, error for not finding 'type' (with `template<typename Tp = T>`)

Comment: Oops, yes, was missing required `typename` keyword.

Comment: besides the missing typenames, it gives the same error "no type named 'type'", could it be some compiler option?

Comment: Thanks, my error was that within `enable_if` I was still using `T` instead of `Tp`

Comment: I'd note that the only necessary change is the introduction of `Tp`. `enable_if` can stay in a template argument.