# How to hide some function in templates?

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a template class

```
template<typename T>
class C{
public:
    void func(){

    }

    // many other functions ...
};
```

Now I want to add a new function `func1()` in it, and I want `func1()` only valid when the class is `C<int>`(i.e. Cstd::string has no member function named `func1()`).
like

```
tempalte<>
class C<int>{
public:
    void func(){

    }

    // many other functions ...

    void func1(){

    }
};

tempalte<>
class C<std::string>{
public:
    void func(){

    }

    // many other functions ...

    // no func1() defined. When C<std::string>().func1() called, the compiler will report error, while C<std::string>().func() called, it will be ok.
};
```

And I just want make the smallest change to `class C`, and I don't want rewrite some redundant codes when making partial specialization .

So is it possible to achieve that?
Some attemps in https://godbolt.org/z/s63z1nsbE, but it does not work.

Comment: Dupe: [SFINAE not working with member function of template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71040425/sfinae-not-working-with-member-function-of-template-class)

Comment: [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69975364/using-enable-if-to-hide-member-function-according-to-template-type) and [dupe3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671379/sfinae-to-enable-nontemplate-member-function) and dupe4: [Simple SFINAE Problem conditionally declaring member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349218/simple-sfinae-problem-conditionally-declaring-member-function)

Comment: @user12002570 And none of the 4 have a big fat "use `requires`" at the top of the accepted answer. :( (One in the dupe list has that, so I left it as the only target.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah though I would have preferred that you just shift that at the top of the dupe list which I have done now. As there are many duplicates available and the dupe list can have 5 items, no point in "removing" the other four from the dupe list and having only one. The more choice/options there is the better.

Answer (score 2):

In C++20 and newer you use `requires`:

```
void func1() requires std::same_as<T, int>
{
    // ...
}
```

Pre-C++20 you have to make the function a template, and use `enable_if`:

```
template <
    typename U = T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, U> && std::is_same_v<U, int>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
>
void func1()
{
    // ...
};
```

There's also the option of using a `static_assert`, but it's usually inferior to `requires`/`enable_if_t`, because even though it lets you specify a custom failure message, it's not "SFINAE-friendly", i.e. it doesn't let others programmatically check whether the function supports this type or not.

```
void func1()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int>, "`func1()` only supports `T=int`!");
}
```

Comment: Yup indeed the static_assert will not scale, and instead of "programmatically check" I would call it "cannot check at compile time if a function exists or not". The version with static_assert will always be considered (as a valid overload) by the compiler and not really hide it.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I mean, you as a human can *"check at compile time if a function exists"* (by getting a build error), hence "programmatically". :P

Comment: that's also a way of looking at it :)

Answer (score 2):

You will either need to use concepts/requires from C++20 or use std::enable_if.

Demo here : https://godbolt.org/z/hqe44Yqor

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename type_t>
class C
{
public:

    void can_always_be_called()
    {
    }

    // With C++ 20 you can use concepts
    void func_cpp20() requires std::same_as<type_t,int>
    {

    }

    // With C++17 (and probably before) you can use SFINAE/enable_if
    // and one step of template indirection
    template<typename arg_t = type_t>
    auto func_cpp17() -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<arg_t,int>,void>
    {
    }
    
};


int main()
{
    C<double> c1;
    c1.can_always_be_called();
    c1.func_cpp20(); // <== does not compile as intended
    c1.func_cpp17(); // <== does not compile as intended

    C<int> c2;
    c2.can_always_be_called();
    c2.func_cpp20();
    c2.func_cpp17();

}
```